# Register a custom listener for a custom auto-configuration Spring starter

Tags: spring-boot

I wrote a custom spring-boot starter. Among other things this module listens to inbound Rabbit messages.

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = "ladisa.${ladisa.macchina.macchinaName}.command")
    public void listenCommand(ComandoStr comando) {
            //TODO: call registered methods 
    }
```

I wouldn’t like to process incoming messages into Spring starter code but I’d like to delegate the execution to methods belonging to the spring application where my starter in used. I’d like to use a custom annotation.

```
    @CommandEventListerner
    public void processCommand(ComandoStr cmd) {
        //TODO: code that precess the event
    }
```

Where **@CommandEventListerner** is my custom annotation to signal my application to use these methods as targets for the execution.
Is it possible instruct Spring to register all methods annotated with i.e.  @CommandEventListerner and execute them all inside a method belonging to a custom spring-starter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a spring-boot standard way. In the starter you can autowire the  ApplicationEventPublisher

```
    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "ladisa.${ladisa.macchina.macchinaName}.command")
    public void listenCommand(ComandoStr comando) {
        publisher.publishEvent(comando); 
    }
```

In the project that uses the starter module, the application can listen to events by registering  methoda with the standard annotation @EventListener

```
    @EventListener
    public void processCommand(ComandoStr cmd) {
        System.out.println(cmd.comando);
    }
```

Spring dispaches events based on the type (in this case ComandoStr).